# Eagle UI: separating hundreds of components that are stacked on top of each other

Tags: eaglecad

I finished a complicated schematic in the free version of Eagle, switched over to the board editor and was encountered by this:

[image]

In case the image doesn't say it all, there are about 100 components all stacked on top of each other with the same origin.

Separating them manually will take ages, is there a way I can fix this automatically so I can place my components?

Comment: Since the software does not know how you wish to place the components, or rotate them, its YOUR task to use the mouse to click and grab and move ALL the components to the location and orientation YOU need.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf absolutely not, the software should place the components so that they can be easily found and moved by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the move tool and type the component designator you wish to place.
Eg: click on move, then type `D5`, and you're holding D5 ready to place somewhere.

Autoplacers are a feature of more expensive tools.

Answer (score 1):

In case of a repeating schematic blocks:

1. backup your current schematic.
2. delete all except one instance, update board editor, place components in desired layout
3. copy/paste the first instance in the schematic editor, update board editor, place new added components in desired layout (matching the layout of the first instance if desired)
4. repeat step 3

If possible (the editor I use has it, I think all editors have it, but haven't used Eagle for years), you can group components, so, in the board editor, group the components after step 2. Next, after updating the board editor in step 3, put the new added components on top of their equivalent components of the first instance. Move away the original group.
Maybe you can also copy/paste the first instance in the board editor as well (after copy/paste in the schematic editor) and then update and back annotate. However, my experience is that that is a terrible way.

In case of functional, non-repeating blocks (and if Eagle allows, my editor does):

1. backup your current schematic.
2. open a new schematic
3. copy/paste a functional schematic block from the original schematic to the new schematic
4. update board editor, place new added components in desired layout
5. repeat step 3 and 4

Answer (score 1):

There are some [ULP scripts](https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-82941/l/the-20-most-popular-eagle-ulps-of-all-time) that might be useful to you.
Take a look at

> - 5) autoplace_v3.ulp by David Moodie
>
> Crude autoplace ULP, adaptation of Cadsoft original IIRC. v4 compatible, creates grouping based on SCH and handles multiple sheets. Uploaded by David Moodie from OptoSci Ltd.

and

> - 7) place50.zip by Matthias Weingart
>
> Simple Autoplacer, run this ulp in the schematic; and exec the resulting script in the new created PCB - it will place all parts of the board to the position in the schematic. Most useful for analog designs. Uploaded by Matthias Weingart from IngBuero fuer wiss. Geraeteentw. - Solutions for embedded electronics.

for example.